# iOS 8 Tabbar controller, different tabs for iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I have requirement to make universal App, which has a tab bar interface, but it has different tabs ordering for iPhone and iPad, for example like iTune Store App for iOS, for iPhone tabs are Music, Films, Search, Tones, and More. But in iPad options are Music, Movies, TV Shows, Audiobooks, TopCharts, Genius, Purchased. What is the best way for doing this in storyboard and by using Size classes. As I don't want to create two storyboards for iPhone and iPad. Ideally I like to do as much setup from storyboard possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can drop two tabbarcontrollers to storyboard, push the right one by device type.

you can also create the uitabbarcontroller programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you have 4 tabbar items for iPhone and 6 tabbar items for iPad. Add all 6 tabbar items in the storyboard design and if the device is iPhone then remove the tabbar items whichever is not needed.

```
NSMutableArray *tabBarControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
[tabBarControllers removeObjectAtIndex:5];
[tabBarControllers removeObjectAtIndex:6];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:tabBarControllers];
```